# Appium. How to install app from apple store

Tags: appium, appium-ios

Previously I've used builds from hockeyapp.
Installation was using url to .ipa file on hockeyapp.
Now I'm trying to do the same but using some url to app store.
Unfortunately it's not working in this way.

Question:

- how to install app from apple store on my real iOS devise with appium?
- how to get url to .ipa file from apple store?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you gonna install app from Apple Store via Appium:

- Appium is using **WebDriverAgent** for iOS Automation
- **WebDriverAgent** should be signed with same **Apple developer account** that your app was signed
- Appium can interact only with the app that was signed *described way*, so it cannot download anything from Apple store and even if you get app from store Appium **would not be able to interact** with it.

Comment: tnx for aswering. To be true I'm not familiar with iOS, could you please describe what does it mean?
I can suggetst that my Apple profile has all needed certificates/signs. As I uderstood WebDrverAgent was installed automatically by Appium. But I have no idea how to install te app =(

Comment: Appium can interact with your app only if its signed with an Apple developer account and you sign WebDriverAgent with the same certificate. But there is no way Appium can download smth from Apple store and interact with app downloaded from the store, its kind of limitation.

Comment: I suggest you read Appium docs to get familiar on how it may work http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/

Comment: will check tnx.